# Entity Framework many to many table insert complex relations

Tags: entity-framework

This is my simplified schema.

[image]

I want to add a contact who is a custodian and attach them to an existing facility. The ContactType just states what type of contact the record is such as a company or individual. In this case the custodian is an individual.
I can insert a contact by itself just fine.

The complication for me is because of the many to many and one to many relationships.

In the controller I have

```
     vm.Contact.Facilities.Add(new Facility { FacilityID = vm.SelectedFacilityID });

    _repo.SaveContact(vm);
```

In the repo

```
            _db.Contacts.Add(vm.Contact);
            _db.SaveChanges();
```

This gives me a foreign key error since it tries to insert a new facility and I have other foreign keys in that table not shown. I don't want to add a facility but just reference the FacilityID.

Convention is to *Not* explicitly try to insert a record in the many to many, FacilityCustodian table directly by doing something like this

```
 var fc = new FacilityCustodian { CustodianFacilityID = vm.SelectedFacilityID };
 vm.Contact.FacilityCustodian.Add(fc);
```

I also tried

```
            foreach (var facility in vm.Contact.Facilities)
            {
                _db.Entry(facility).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
            }
```

Most of the examples I have seen don't have both relationships so I'm not sure how to proceed.

Thanks for any help.

ADDED CODE

```
using Licensing.Models;
namespace Licensing
{
using System.Data.Entity;
public class Context : DbContext
{
    public Context()
        : base("name=Context")
    {
    }
    public virtual DbSet<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<ContactType> ContactTypes { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Facility> Facilities { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<FacilityCandler> FacilityCustodians { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Contact>()
            .Property(e => e.FName)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Contact>()
            .Property(e => e.LName)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Contact>()
            .HasMany(e => e.Facilities)
            .WithRequired(e => e.Contact)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Contact>()
            .HasMany(e => e.FacilityCustodians)
            .WithRequired(e => e.Contact)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.CustodianFacilityID)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ContactType>()
            .Property(e => e.Type)
            .IsUnicode(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ContactType>()
            .HasMany(e => e.Contacts)
            .WithRequired(e => e.ContactType)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Facility>()
            .HasMany(e => e.FacilityCustodians)
            .WithRequired(e => e.Facility)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.CustodianFacilityID)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }

}
}

namespace Licensing.Models
{
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Data.Entity.Spatial;

[Table("Contact")]
public class Contact
{

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Contact()
    {
        Facilities = new HashSet<Facility>();
        FacilityCustodians = new HashSet<FacilityCustodian>();

    }

    [Key]
    public int ContactID { get; set; }

    public int ContactTypeID { get; set; }


    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z'.\s]+$", ErrorMessage = "Enter a valid Name")]
    [StringLength(150)]
    public string FName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z'\s]+$", ErrorMessage = "Enter a valid Name")]
    [StringLength(150)]
    public string LName { get; set; }


    public virtual ContactType ContactType { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Facility> Facilities { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<FacilityCustodian> FacilityCustodians { get; set; }
}
}


using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Licensing.Models
{
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

[Table("Facility")]
public class Facility
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Facility()
    {
        FacilityCustodians = new HashSet<FacilityCustodian>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int FacilityID { get; set; }

    public int ContactID { get; set; }

    public virtual Contact Contact { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<FacilityCustodian> FacilityCustodians { get; set; }
}
}

using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace Licensing.Models
{
[Table("FacilityCustodian")]
public partial class FacilityCustodian
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int CustodianFacilityID { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int CustodianContactID { get; set; }

    public virtual Contact Contact { get; set; }

    public virtual Facility Facility { get; set; }
}
}

namespace Licensing.Models
{
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

[Table("ContactType")]
public class ContactType
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public ContactType()
    {
        Contacts = new HashSet<Contact>();
    }

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int ContactTypeID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(10)]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
}
}
```

UPDATE Working Code

```
  var existingFacility = _repo.GetFacilityByFacilityID(vm.SelectedFacilityID);
                    vm.Contact.LName = vm.LName;
                    vm.Contact.FName = vm.FName;
                    vm.Contact.Name = vm.FName + " " + vm.LName;
                    vm.Contact.ContactTypeID = 1;
                    vm.Contact.FacilityCustodians.Add(existingFacility);

                _db.Contacts.Add(vm.Contact);
                _db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: hi Van you please share you model clases and dbcontext class so that I can try on local pc please it will be faster if you paste here

Comment: The example here is a striped down version of the entities I am using but I updated the question with the relevant entities and context.

Comment: You only have to attach `new Facility` to the context before adding it to the Contact.

Comment: Gert, I tried that. Attaching an entity of type 'Licensing.Models.Facility' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value. This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting the state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the graph have conflicting key values. This may be because some entities are new and have not yet received database-generated key values. In this case use the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state to track the graph and then set the state of non-new entities to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' as appropriate.

Comment: So first check if it's already attached and if so, take the attached one. However, I wonder why it's already attached. Looks like your context's live cycle is too long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this  Since I dont have complete folder I tried to simplify the model all classes are name mentioned in diagram but I create. Below are my model classes . The import thing to note is that read the entoty from contecxt first and then updated the values and set entitystate accordingly . This will solve your issue .

Model classes :-

```
           public class ContactType
        {
            public int ContactTypeId { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }
        public class Contact
        {
            public int ContactId { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public int ContactTypeId { get; set; }
            [ForeignKey("ContactTypeId")]
            public virtual ContactType ContactType { get; set; }

            public virtual ICollection<Facility> Facilities { get; set; } 
        }
        public class FacilityCustodian
        {
            public int FacilityId { get; set; }

            public int ContactTypeId { get; set; }
            [ForeignKey("ContactId")]
            public virtual Contact Contact { get; set; }
             [ForeignKey("FacilityId")]
            public virtual 
                Facility Facility { get; set; }
        }
        public class Facility
        {
            public int FacilityId { get; set; }
            public string Location { get; set; }
            public int ContactId { get; set; }
            [ForeignKey("ContactId")]
            public virtual Contact Contact { get; set; }
            public virtual ICollection<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
        }

-- here I am showing you to update existing contact and add a new facility to it . same as you case you want to update facility ...

    using (var ctx = new SampleDbContext())
        {
           //this is important to read the entity first .
            var contact = ctx.Contacts.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.ContactId ==vm.Contact.ContactId);
            if (contact != null)
            {
                // Since facilityId is a primary key I set it to autoincrement so I dont have to set it .You can set if it is not primarykey 
                contact.Name = "Updated";
                // update the entity and add new information inthis i am adding facility
                var facility = new Facility
                {
                    Location = "LocA",
                    // assiging same entity to facility so that it will not treat it as a new contact 
                    Contact = contact
                };

                contact.Facilities.Add(facility);
              // Finaly update the state of the entity .
               ctx.Entry(contact).State = EntityState.Modified;

                ctx.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
```

After this it will not insert new contact when you save in . In my example I choose to add new facility but keep contact same . You can do same with facility but the concept is same . First read the object from EF coontext update values which you need to update and set state to Modified . This will tell that all other Entities in graph are same expect which you modified.

SQL Profiler Query to make sure Update happn for Contact and insert for facility

```
  exec sp_executesql N'UPDATE [dbo].[Contacts]
  SET [Name] = @0, [ContactTypeId] = @1
  WHERE ([ContactId] = @2)
  ',N'@0 nvarchar(max) ,@1 int,@2 int',@0=N'Updated',@1=1,@2=1
 go

 exec sp_executesql N'INSERT [dbo].[Facilities]([Location], [ContactId],              [Contact_ContactId])
           VALUES (@0, @1, @2)
          SELECT [FacilityId]
        FROM [dbo].[Facilities]
    WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [FacilityId] = scope_identity()',N'@0nvarchar(max) ,@1 int,@2 int',@0=N'LocA',@1=1,@2=1
```

go

Comment: Thanks Yashveer, I tried your example and the insert into the join table never happens. The insert into Contact works and the Update of Facility works but there is no insert into the FacilityCustodian table. I think the confusing part is the 2 relationships between Contact and Facility.

Comment: @forwheeler thanks for trying .Now I have your model class it wil be easier to answer it correctly .

Comment: Can you please explain the purpose of Facility Table It has only FacilityId ContactId nothing more

Comment: The real table has Active, location and PropertyID. PropertyID is a foreign key to a Property table. The sample I used here is small.

Comment: I found an issue with the relationships in the join table which I am investigating.

Comment: @forwheeler ok . I dont understand FacilityCustodians  table purpose .  I think this should be a junction table when you add/update an facility . In your code I dont see purpose of add facility to contact again if facility is the same .

Comment: I thought it was working but I still have the same issue. The FacilityCustodian table is a junction table what allows me to record many custodians to many facilities. Contacts can be many types such as Company contacts, property contacts, facility contacts. The one to many relationship handles that. The many to many is for custodians which will work at a facility. I can't use the one to many because there may be many custodians working at a facility and the one to may only allows one custodian. Remember I am only showing a small portion of the tables in the database.

Comment: So to summarize: I don't want to add a new facility, I want to use an existing facility. I want to add a new contact (custodian). I want to add a record in the FacilityCustodian table to represent the new custodian working at the existing facility.

Comment: I was able to get this working based on Yashveer's recommendation. I first fixed the table relationships since there were 2 relationships between the Contact and Facility tables. I then get the existing facility and add it to the contact. I added the working code to my original question.

Comment: @forwheeler glad to hear that :)

Comment: @forwheeler I hope you find  my answer is useful .